# How to enable / disable web application compression via command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, appcmd

I'm running iis 10 on windows server 2016.
I need to enable content compression for some web application and disable it for others.
These check boxes specifically.
[image: iis content compression]
<sub>(source: [customerscanvas.com](https://customerscanvas.com/docs/cc/images/httpCompressionEnable_02.png))</sub>

Is there a way to do it via command line?
preferably via powershell / appcmd.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/using-configuration-editor-generate-scripts

Comment: Thank you, but there are a lot of sections in this doc and I couldn't find what I'm looking for. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You could enable and disable compression for site using below command:

```
appcmd set config "site1" /section:urlCompression /doDynamicCompression:True

appcmd set config "urlsample" /section:urlCompression /doStaticCompression:True
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yep. this is what I was looking for! Much appreciated. Thank you.
Just to clarify for future references - If you want to set it for a specific web app located under under a site - you should use "site1/webapp" instead "site1". The picture I attached doesn't fully represent my iis configuration but I couldn't find something more similar to what I wanted.
i.e:
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/V1.0" /section:urlCompression /doStaticcompression:false

Comment: in powershell:
`& $Env:windir/System32/inetsrv/appcmd.exe  set config /section:urlCompression /doStaticCompression:False`